# Elasticsearch Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Am trying to convert this elastic search query using java api

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "random_score": {}
        }
      ],
       "score_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

this is what i have done

```
  QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction());
```

Am trying to return all matches in a random order, does not seem to work

Comment: The java code, looks to be working fine. Could you please let me know what output or error did you observe?

Comment: There was no errors, the problem is i needed the output to come randomly whenever i do a `GET request`

Comment: Could you please let me know which version of ES are you using? I've tried in version 7.7 and it works like a charm!! I get random results every time I do a `GET`. Note that at times I do see same results however if you notice their `_score` value, it appears different everytime.

Comment: am using `bonsai.io` for my elasticsearch and its version `7.2.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the below example and what I observed. It should probably help. I've created a sample mapping with a single field `myfield` of `text` type.

### Sample Documents:

```
POST my_function_index/_doc/1
{
  "myfield": "Doesn't remind me of anything"
}

POST my_function_index/_doc/2
{
  "myfield": "I like playing in sand, what's mine is yours"
}

POST my_function_index/_doc/3
{
  "myfield": "I like travelling backwards in the fog"
}
```

### Java API Code

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.lucene.search.function.FunctionScoreQuery.ScoreMode;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.QueryBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.FunctionScoreQueryBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.index.query.functionscore.ScoreFunctionBuilders;
import org.elasticsearch.search.SearchHit;
import org.elasticsearch.search.builder.SearchSourceBuilder;

public class FunctionScore {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
                RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http")));
        
        SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        
        //Below is the logic for creating functionScore via API
        FunctionScoreQueryBuilder functionScore = QueryBuilders.functionScoreQuery(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery(), ScoreFunctionBuilders.randomFunction());
        functionScore.scoreMode(ScoreMode.SUM);
        sourceBuilder.query(functionScore);

        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
        searchRequest.indices("my_function_index");
        searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);
        
        //The API Response you get
        SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);       
        SearchHit[] searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
        
        //Printing the results
        for(SearchHit theHit: searchHits) {
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(theHit);
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------");
        }

    }

}
```

### Response Observed:

Below are two sample responses where you get the *same order of documents* however note their `_score` values. They are different.

Note that each time I run the above API, I get a different response. I guess due to my index size being 3, at some point I am bound to get same order.

If you have more documents, the variations would be a lot more.

**First Instance**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_score" : 0.8976933,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "I like travelling backwards in the fog"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 0.85642433,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "I like playing in sand, what's mine is yours"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 0.42347366,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "Doesn't remind me of anything"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
```

**Second Instance:**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "3",
  "_score" : 0.8440073,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "I like travelling backwards in the fog"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "2",
  "_score" : 0.79675066,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "I like playing in sand, what's mine is yours"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------
{
  "_index" : "my_function_index",
  "_type" : "_doc",
  "_id" : "1",
  "_score" : 0.7430876,
  "_source" : {
    "myfield" : "Doesn't remind me of anything"
  }
}
-----------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this helps